# SharePoint SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog opens the page then closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have a custom Edit form, open another custom new item form for a different list

When I use `window.open(pageUrl);` it opens OK in a new tab.

But I want it to be a popup So I use:

`var options = { url: pageUrl+"&IsDlg=1",width: 700, height: 800 };
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);`

And even if the popup page has no code running, it shows and immediately closes so the user can't take any Action.

Any one knows how to make the popup stay?
Thanks